# How to use ALT tag correctly?

Tags: html, alt

I have used the ALT tags for all my images with this format:

```
<a alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT" href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MEHRDQvoG-c/Ux0mL1mlJII/AAAAAAAAGg8/S9h3KjhJ6YQ/s1600/jquery-lightbox-with-dark-background.png" imageanchor="1"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MEHRDQvoG-c/Ux0mL1mlJII/AAAAAAAAGg8/S9h3KjhJ6YQ/s320/jquery-lightbox-with-dark-background.png" style="height:100%; width:100%;" /></a>
```

But I was surprised when the image checker tools sensed their alt tags as "missing". I supposed I had to insert the "alt" tag after the "img src" tag like that:

```
<a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MEHRDQvoG-c/Ux0mL1mlJII/AAAAAAAAGg8/S9h3KjhJ6YQ/s1600/jquery-lightbox-with-dark-background.png" imageanchor="1"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-MEHRDQvoG-c/Ux0mL1mlJII/AAAAAAAAGg8/S9h3KjhJ6YQ/s320/jquery-lightbox-with-dark-background.png" alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT" style="height:100%; width:100%;" /></a>
```

Tell me please will this style correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `alt` should be only used in `<applet>, <area>, <img>, <input>`

> alt - `<applet>, <area>, <img>, <input>` -    Alternative text in case an
>   image can't be displayed.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

here is a snippet of `img`:

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="image">
```

Answer (score 1):

alt is a property of IMG tag and not of A tag. It stands for alternative text to be shown or read by screen readers. So the second example you provided is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

The alt attribute must be on the  element and not on the hyperlink  element.

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing the "alt" tag and the "title" tag.

The "alt" tag is used with images:

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" alt="image">
```

The title tag can be used with BOTH images and links

```
<img src="someImage.jpg alt="image" title="Some Image">
<a href="someLink.com" title="This is some link">
```

There wouldn't be any need for an "alt" tag on a traditional link, because even if the link was bad, there would still be text wrapped in the anchor indicating what it is:

```
<a href="someLink.com">Link to some link</a>
```

With the image, the "alt" property value only displays when the image, for whatever reason, isn't available.